# Bird identification: song two low, two high, five short

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

This morning I heard a bird that had a song which was two low notes, two high notes, and five quick notes in succession. Location is New England.

Is there any way, short of asking an expert, that I can find out what a bird is from a description of its song or call?

**Update - Bird Song Uploaded**

I have been able to host a sound clip on Vocaroo:

[Unknown bird, Massachusetts, forested suburban environment](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1tmGy8Zz1PO)

Comment: It's hard to say by your description. But you could try a song database: http://www.xeno-canto.org/ Click "explore by region", drag a box over New England. I got 125 species. It will take a while, but perhaps you find yours (125 is not that much).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Nice website! Haven't heard of it before. I will add it to my repertoire of ID tools. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

Best guess is that the bird is a Song Sparrow, *Melospiza melodia*. Cornell Lab of Ornithology has a good website for basic facts about birds. [Here is the account for Song Sparrow.](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Song_Sparrow/id) There is a sample of typical song, but there can occasionally be some variety.

The song is kind of complex and the recording you linked to seems to garble or not capture some of the song, but the changes in phrases throughout the duration seem to match as does the pitch of most of the phrases.

Comment: +1 The first [audio](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Song_Sparrow/sounds) here is very close to OP's bird's song.